# Customize duplicate records in SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to customize duplicate rows considering 2 columns in MS AccessSQL query.

1) If PrivateName of any teachers are different then Take PrivateName only.
2) If PrivateName of any teachers are same then Take Concat(PrivateName, 1st Letter of LastName).
3) If Result is still contains same teacher names then Concate(PrivateName, LastName)

I have `tblTeachers` named table with following data.

```
TeacherID   PrivateName   LastName
1           aa            1
2           b             2
3           c             3
4           d             4
5           e             5
6           ab            6
7           g             7
8           h             8
9           i             9
10          aa            10
11          j             11
12          k             12
13          l             13
14          m             14
15          n             15
16          o             16
17          p             17
18          q             18
19          r             19
20          b             20
```

I want below as output:

```
TeacherID   TeacherName
1           aa 1
2           b 2
3           c
4           d
5           e
6           ab 6
7           g
8           h
9           i
10          aa 10
11          j
12          k
13          l
14          m
15          n
16          o
17          p
18          q
19          r
20          b 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to a subquery which finds the number of occurrenced of each private name.  In the case where a private name does occur for more than one teacher, then append the last name to the private name as the output.

```
SELECT
    t1.TeacherID,
    IIF(t2.cnt > 1, t1.PrivateName & " " & STR(t1.LastName), t1.PrivateName) AS TeacherName
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PrivateName, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY PrivateName
) t2
    ON t1.PrivateName = t2.PrivateName
ORDER BY
    t1.TeacherID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is perfectly fine (if I understand the question correctly).  Another way to write this which might have better performance is:

```
select t.TeacherID,
       iif( exists (select 1
                    from t as t2
                    where t2.PrivateName = t.PrivateName and
                          t2.TeacherId <> t.teacherId
                   ),
            t.PrivateName & " " & str(t1.LastName),
            t.PrivateName
           ) as TeacherName
from t
order by t.TeacherID;
```

In particular the `exists` can take advantage of an index on `(name, TeacherId)`.